# Chrome insspect showing weird == $0 in the elements tab

Tags: google-chrome, element, inspect

So this little thing annoys me so much. What is this, and how do I get rid of it?

It appears on any element in the document, any website.

Nothing on Google.

[image: What is this]

Edit: I didn't see this up until recently. It's pretty confusing and annoying and I want to know how to hide it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is ==$0 in chrome developer tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-is-0-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: It's a little visual prompt that this is the currently selected element.  You can enter $0 in the console for the same info.  I think they are just highlighting the API so more people are aware of it (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api)

Comment: Possibly not. I'm trying to hide it - is there a way? nothing regarding hiding it comes up in that page