# What does == $0 mean in the DOM view in developer tools?

Tags: html, select, element

When I'm in Developer Tools and select an html-element,
it puts '== $0' behind it like this:[image: $0].

What does this mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-does-0-double-equals-dollar-zero-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I know it's easy to forget, but in the future, please always remember to Google first: a search for your original question title, `What does == $0 mean?` would have taken you right away to the duplicate question - a much quicker way and more convenient to find your answer.

Comment: I typed ==$0 in the question title and it shows you a bunch of questions that were already asked, and it didn't show any $0 questions my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you can write `$0` in the developer console to get the active DOM element. You can see the image I have provided.

[[image: Picture of example[1]]