# toggleClass only adds 'class' as attribute to HTML element - not the acctuall class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an odd problem. I have used toggleClass before and had it working nicely. Now however only the 'class' attribute gets added to the element but no actuall class. Like this:

```
$("#slideButtonMenu").click(function(){
  $("#sidebar").toggleClass("slideLeft");
});
```

```css
.slideLeft {
  left: -220px;
}
```

This is what I get while inspecting the element. Before click on "#slideButtonMenu":

```
<aside id="sidebar"> == $0
```

When/after clicking the button:

```
<aside id="sidebar" class> == $0
```

Wanted outcome after first click:

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="slideLeft"> == $0
```

I don't really know what the `== $0` means but I don't think it affects this. If I change toggleClass to addClass it successfully adds the class... but then I obviously can't slide the menu back out again.

Comment: This behaviour can occur when the `click` event is triggered an even number of times. Have you duplicated the `click` handler?

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/2oehqmzc/ . Please create a [MCVE] showing the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ==$0 (double equals dollar zero) mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-does-0-double-equals-dollar-zero-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Please read the question. It is not about `== $0`, and OP acknowledges that it's probably unrelated.

Comment: As Rory says, you are most likely binding your click event multiple times somehow.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and Turnip - for what it is woth I just changed to use .on('click'.....) didn't change it. I will read up on how to check this as you say and I'll get back to y'all with updates. Thanks for now

Comment: @Turnip and Rory - Yay thanks! went here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times and added .unbind() and it works like a charm now thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to unbind the event. Something is wrong elsewhere in your code. Check that you aren't accidentally loading the jQuery library more than once.

Comment: @Turnip ok, I'll look in to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rory McCrossan and @Turnip suggested my click was binded wrongly.

The answer was to add unbind(), like so:

```
$("#slideButtonMenu").unbind().click(function(){
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("slideLeft");
});
```

Works now!

EDIT:
According to @Turnip this should not be needed if everything with my code was done correctly but for now I am just gonna YOLO and go with this for my POC tmrw.

EDIT2:
Ok, found the wrongings. I did load this script twice:

```
$("#slideButtonMenu").click(function(){
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("slideLeft");
});
```

When changed that so it only loaded once it worked without .unbind()