# Remove the contents under classname using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove the everything under the classname: social-share using JavaScript

**HTML:** This is what it looks like when I grab the code from chrome inspector.

```
<div class="social-share">
      [shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="26444890"]
</div>
```

**HTML:** This is what exactly looks like inside the chrome inspector

```
<div class="social-share">
"
[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="26444890"]
" == $0
</div>
```

Comment: what is stopping you from using `document.querySelector('.social-share').textContent = ''`

Comment: do you want to `social-share` div to be empty OR cleaned from junk?

Comment: See [What does ==$0 (double equals dollar zero) mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36999739/1048572) for why the second snippet is irrelevant

Comment: Bergi, I stated the fact of my observation and the second snippet might be of help on how this issue can be solved.

Comment: @Atlast, spot on mate.

Comment: @kukkuz It's not that I stopping myself, Its just I don't know how to. That's why I asked.

Comment: @user354355 oops, didn't mean to sound rude... just thought it was a simple one...

Comment: No offense taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` to clear the contents of the element after it has been selected:

```
// select element with class 'social-share:
var social_share = document.querySelector('.social-share');

// Set it's contents to an empty string
social_share.innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.social-share').empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social-share"> content
      <div>content</div>
</div>
```

Jquery empty() might be help you. It will remove every thing inside social-share class