# Browser will move style tags in head to body

Tags: html, css

I wrote the style tag in head, but the browser will move it to the `body` and leave an empty string on top of it. And it will have an empty space in the browser in Mac.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>123</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

That extra spacing is an empty string in body (highlighted in image), 
not margin or padding, and it will do the same thing in Firefox and Safari.

How do I get rid of it?

[My HTML file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bwm6q0e5d4lmf7/test.html?dl=0)

Comment: Try to take out the type="text/css out of the style tag.

Comment: Already tried it, nothing changed.

Comment: is there anything else inside the `<head></head>`? If yes, please copy paste them here too (format them properly of couse)

Comment: Looks like you use Chrome on Mac. I've tried your code on Chrome, Edge and Firefox on Windows and it works fine. Maybe there are other things you didn't include in your post?

Comment: This post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-does-0-double-equals-dollar-zero-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: @YongQuan I removed all the tags (meta, title, etc...) to test it one by one, so there is nothing else inside the `head`.

Comment: Probably a garbage control character. If removing everything doesn't work your best bet is to rewrite your page from scratch and ensure it is saved with the right file encoding.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this from somewhere and possibly bring in a special character by acident?

Comment: I added a file download link.

Comment: @TravisActon That file is from `Polymer init`.

Comment: @Rob, Dream_Cap: The asker knows what the $0 means. They literally stated in the question that the first node behind the style element within the body element is an empty text node. The question is how the style element got there in the first place.

Comment: I found one special character in your code before style tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*After View Your Source Code I Get The Idea Why This Happen, actually there is one special character I found In you code.*
 It's your code link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FK89ZCXW8WDC

You can see the special character before the style tag start.

Comment: Oh god... Thank you.

Comment: Thank u :) happy to help bro :)