# html page does not load properly

Tags: html, localization, browser-support

I got an issue with the loading of some links from my website, the HTML content does not load correctly as shown in the attached image.
[image]

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"><title>بنك الشمال يحدد 2020/10/27 موعداً للإفصاح عن البيانات المالية للربع الثالث</title>   <meta name="description" content=""> <meta name="author" content="nizar"></head><body style=" direction: rtl;font-size: 1.2rem;" > <div style="padding:20px;width: auto;margin: 20px auto;"><h3>بنك الشمال يحدد 2020/10/27 موعداً للإفصاح عن البيانات المالية للربع الثالث</h3>

<p><span style="color:#999999">21-09-2020</span></p>

<hr>
<p>أعلن بنك الشمال عن عزمه الإفصاح عن البيانات المالية الربعية للفترة المنتهية في 2020/9/30، وذلك يوم الثلاثاء الموافق 2020/10/27 .</p>

<hr>
<p><a class="more-btn" href="#" target="_blank">عرض المزيد</a></p>
</div><style> h3{font-size: 1.3rem;text-align: justify;color: #862254;margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 0px; }p{text-align: justify;font-size: 1.2rem;margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 0px;}.more-btn,input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {font-size: 1rem; background-color:#862254; border: none;color: white;padding: 10px 20px;border-radius:7px;text-decoration: none;margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer; } @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {.more-btn{display:none;}}</style></body></html>
```

Comment: works fine in the snippet

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Saving the HTML as posted in a html file and opening it, also works just fine - perhaps the device or browser you're using is the problem

Comment: Make sure you declared the encoding of your doument. For this you add the following code as you did in the (working) snippet.

<meta charset="utf-8"/>

Comment: that's the weird thing, I cant not figure out what is the cause.  the encoding and charset it is fine, and the issue is non-persistent, it appears in different browsers

Comment: Try clearing the caches in your browsers. Maybe you tested it before you made bigger changes. And now it's getting the old data from the cache.

Comment: Safari browser moves head content to the body tag, which causes the issue , and after search I found this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577201/browser-will-move-style-tags-in-head-to-body I re-wrote the code and it works fine,