# Python Beautifulsoup Tag Selection - Complex Issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have `soup` with the following tag/information:

```
<table class="first_day info"> ==$0
<tbody>
 ...
```

I am trying to access this table but can't seem to get syntax right.  I think it has to do with the `==$0` but I can't figure it out.

I'm using the following code/syntax:

```
briefs = briefs_meta.find("table",class_='first_day info')
```

and I've also tried:

```
briefs_meta = soup.find_all("table",{"class": "first_day info"})
```

But all I get is an empty result.

Insight?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a dynamic table? Check HTML source code. Also note that your problem has nothing to do with [*==$0*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-does-0-double-equals-dollar-zero-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: How would I tell if it were a dynamic table?  If it is does that cause problems?

Comment: Try something like `assert "<table class="first_day info">" in requests.get(URL).text`. In case of `AssertionError` - `table` is dynamic. It also might be a preventing of web scraping

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: @Andersson  I'm able to get information (including desired information if I use simple tag code:  `brief_meta = soup.find_all("table")`.  So I'm able to scrape.  But it gives me tons more info than I want.  Hence trying to cut down with use of `class`

Comment: Try something like: `soup.select("table.first_day.info")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using BeautifulSoup to search multiple CSS classes, it is usually better to use a [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class). For example:

```
for table in soup.select("table.first_day.info"):
```

This would then match:

```
<table class="info first_day">
```

or:

```
<table class="first_day info">
```

Comment: This works.  Can you explain a bit more why `select` and this particular syntax work?  Thanks.

Comment: There is a good explanation in the docs I linked to. Click on the select link, it is near the bottom of the paragraph I think.

Comment: Better still the [selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) link is useful too.