# dynamic html content from javascript (using jquery methods)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jquery is loaded in my html prior to my js code.
Then in my puzzle.js I have :

```js
class Puzzle {
  constructor(ID, Name, Status) {
    this.ID = "main" + ID;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Status = Status;
    this.mainDiv = "";
  }

  generateDiv() {
    this.mainDiv = '<div id="' + this.ID + '"/>';
    $(this.mainDiv).addClass("puzzle");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var puzzle = new Puzzle(1, "MyPuzzle", 1);
  puzzle.generateDiv();
  $("#Puzzles").append(puzzle.mainDiv);
})
```

```css
.puzzle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  border 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Puzzles"></div>
```

And the div get's added with the nice ID field but the class does not. In fact anything I do to the div "jquery-style" does nothing (but also no console error)

I noticed that in the inspector (chrome) the div appears as

```
<div id="main1"></div> == $0
```

Not sure what it means or if relevant.

What am I doing wrong ???

Comment: I'm aware I could easily add the class in the html code, but I pretend to do other jquery actions on my html. Things way more complex. And I need a platform for doing so.

Comment: the `== $0` in chrome  is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-does-0-double-equals-dollar-zero-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: Read up on [the preferred way to create html using jQuery here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619445/the-preferred-way-of-creating-a-new-element-with-jquery)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this could never work: `$(this.mainDiv).addClass("puzzle");` since you are in a class and jQuery doesn't runs in that context.

Comment: oh, you are totally wrong. $(".template").clone() works like a charm inside my class. I think the root error is that things must be in the DOM before you can find them via $( __ )  but im still investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the jQuery version of the div:

```
this.mainDiv = $(this.mainDiv).addClass("puzzle");
```

Otherwise you add the class to something that is discarded in the next line.

Taking into account what's [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619445/the-preferred-way-of-creating-a-new-element-with-jquery):

> `var $div = $("<div>", {id: "foo", "class": "a"});`

And Mark Baijens' comment:

> It's common to prepend a dollar sign to variables that contain jQuery objects

You could do something like the following:

```js
class Puzzle {
  constructor(ID, Name, Status) {
    this.ID = "main" + ID;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Status = Status;
    this.$mainDiv = null;
  }

  generateDiv() {
    this.$mainDiv = $("<div>", {id: this.ID, "class": "puzzle"});
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var puzzle = new Puzzle(1, "MyPuzzle", 1);
  puzzle.generateDiv();
  $("#Puzzles").append(puzzle.$mainDiv);
})
```

```css
.puzzle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  border 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Puzzles"></div>
```

Comment: simply instantiating the div as `this.mainDiv = $('<div id="'+this.ID+'"/>');` instead of the original `this.mainDiv = '<div id="' + this.ID + '"/>';` will also fix the thing

Comment: @javirs Best practice would be to change `this.mainDiv` to `this.$mainDiv` so you can easily see there is a jQuery object stored in that variable if you use that solution. It's common to prepend a dollar sign to variables that contain jQuery objects.

Comment: didnt event know $name was a valid variable name, Thank you SO much

Comment: @MarkBaijens I added your hint to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @javirs I also updated my answer to show the use of best practices.

Comment: this question / answer should be published in a book ;)